# How to mutate a boxed value type (primitive or struct) in C#/IL

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

Related to [How to mutate a boxed struct using IL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937935/how-to-mutate-a-boxed-struct-using-il#) I am trying to change the value of a boxed value type but in a generic way, so trying to implement the following method:

```
void MutateValueType<T>(object o, T v) where T : struct
```

So the following should be possible:

```
var oi = (object)17;
MutateValueType<int>(oi, 43);
Console.WriteLine(oi); // 43

var od = (object)17.7d;
MutateValueType<double>(od, 42.3);
Console.WriteLine(od); // 42.3
```

I am failing to get it this to work on .NET Framework (see comment by @hvd that the implementation without `typeof(Program).Module` works on other runtimes). I have implemented this as seen below. However, this fails when calling the delegate `del` with a:

```
System.Security.VerificationException: 'Operation could destabilize the runtime.'
```

Here is the implementation I have come up with:

```
public static void MutateValueType<T>(object o, T v)
{
    var dynMtd = new DynamicMethod("EvilMutateValueType", 
        typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(T) });
    var il = dynMtd.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);           // object
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, typeof(T));  // T&
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);           // T (argument value)
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stobj, typeof(T));  // stobj !!T
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);               

    var del = (Action<object, T>)dynMtd.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, T>));
    del(o, v);
}
```

The above should be equivalent to the below IL, that works, but still the above fails, so the question is why this doesn't work.

```
  .method public hidebysig static void Mutate<T>(object o, !!T Value) cil managed aggressiveinlining
  {
    .maxstack  2
    ldarg.0
    unbox !!T
    ldarg.1
    stobj !!T
    ret
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure its possible to completely replace the contents of the box, and not sure why you think it should be (at least, in a generic fashion).

Comment: Because `unbox` simply returns a managed pointer to the value, or in other words address of memory containing the value type. Assigning a new value to this should be possible. This should correspond to a method returning `ref` e.g. `ref T Unbox<T>(object o)`, in fact I think this could be implemented in IL and then used to the above.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Consider a simple `struct Evil { int i; public override string ToString() { ++i; return i.ToString(); } }`, then `object o = new Evil();`. Now, the spec requires `o.ToString() != o.ToString()` -- that is, the spec requires the runtime to support in-place updates of boxed values. Given that the runtime is required to support that anyway, and given that my example doesn't make use of anything that actually requires co-operation from the value type in question, it seems clear to me that what the OP is after should be possible.

Comment: @hvd - the spec requires that *members* of structs be updatable. It doesn't require that the *entire* struct be replacable. I.e. it doesn't require that the `this` assignment possible in `struct` constructors be generally available.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In my example, I can just as easily put `this = new Evil { i = i + 1 };` to modify the entire struct. Struct assignment has never been limited to constructors.

Comment: FWIW, the exact code in this question works, without any modifications, in Mono and in .NET Core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `DynamicMethod` by default requires verifiable code, whereas your own code (including custom IL) is by default allowed to be unverifiable.

You can treat the `DynamicMethod` as part of your own module, allowing it to contain unverifiable IL, by specifying the module:

```
var dynMtd = new DynamicMethod("EvilMutateValueType",
    typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(T) }, typeof(Program).Module);
// Use whatever class you have available here.              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Despite some other issues in PEVerify making it hard to get good diagnostics, it looks like this is intended to at least not be verifiable:

> **III.1.8.1.2.2 Controlled-mutability managed pointers**
>
> The `readonly.` prefix and `unbox` instructions can produce what is called a *controlled-mutability managed pointer*. Unlike ordinary managed pointer types, a controlled-mutability managed pointer is not *verifier-assignable-to* (§III.1.8.1.2.3) ordinary managed pointers; e.g., it cannot be
>   passed as a byref argument to a method. At control flow points, a controlled-mutability managed pointer can be merged with a managed pointer of the same type to yield a controlled-mutability managed pointer.
>
> Controlled-mutability managed pointers can only be used in the following ways:
>
> 1. As the object parameter for an `ldfld`, `ldflda`, `stfld`, `call`, `callvirt`, or `constrained. callvirt` instruction.
> 2. As the pointer parameter to a `ldind.*` or `ldobj` instruction.
> 3. As the source parameter to a `cpobj` instruction.
>
> All other operations (including `stobj`, `stind.*`, `initobj`, and `mkrefany`) are invalid.
>
> [...]

But it looks like it's intended to still be correct:

> **III.4.29 stobj – store a value at an address**
>
> [...]
>
> ***Correctness:***
>
> Correct CIL ensures that *dest* is a pointer to `T` and the type of *src* is *verifier-assignable-to* `T`.
>
> [...]

Note that there is no restriction on controlled-mutability managed pointers here, any pointer to `T` is allowed.

Therefore, ensuring that no verification happens for your IL is the right way to go.

Comment: awesome this works. Thank you very much. Perhaps you could add a note at the end with the final complete code for this, if you like.

Answer (score 3):

One solution, is by making an `Unbox` method in IL that calls `unbox` and returns a `ref` to the type contained in the object:

```
.method public hidebysig static !!T&  Unbox<T>(object o) cil managed aggressiveinlining
{
  .maxstack  1
  ldarg.0
  unbox !!T
  ret
}
```

And then using this like:

```
public static void MutateValueType<T>(object o, T v)
{
    ref T ub = ref Unsafe.Unbox<T>(o);
    ub = v;
}
```

This correctly outputs:

```
        var oi = (object)17;
        MutateValueType<int>(oi, 43);
        Console.WriteLine(oi); // 43

        var od = (object)17.7d;
        MutateValueType<double>(od, 42.3);
        Console.WriteLine(od); // 42.3
```

NOTE: This requires C# 7 support for `ref` returns.

This might be added to say https://github.com/DotNetCross/Memory.Unsafe but it must also be possible with `il.Emit` also, so I am looking for that.