# How to modify the boxed value without creating a new object in C#?

Tags: c#, clr, boxing, value-type, unboxing

How to modify the boxed value without creating a new object in C#?

E.g. if I have `object o = 5;` and I want to change the value of the boxed `5` to `6`, how can I do that?

The `o = 6;` will create a new object on the heap and assign the reference to that object to the `o`. Are there any other ways to change the boxed value?

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724042/how-to-mutate-a-boxed-value-type-primitive-or-struct-in-c-il

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the "boxing" yourself, than you can modify it.

```
class Box
{
     public int Value { get;set;}
}
```

This prevents the automatic boxing.

If you define yourself an conversion operator

```
     public static Box operator(int value) => new Box() { Value = value }
```

You can keep the same syntax as above. But this syntax will create a new object as you see. To modify the object, you would have to

```
  Box b = 5;
  object o = b;
  ((Box)o).Value = 6;
 // or
  b.Value = 6;
```

Comment: Artful solution. Thank you.