# C# Reflection - How to set field value for struct

Tags: c#, reflection, struct, reflection.emit

How can I set value into struct field - `myStruct.myField` with reflection using DynamicMethod? When I call `setter(myStruct, 111)` value was not set, because `MyStruct` is value type. `Console.WriteLine(myStruct.myField)` shows value 3.

How to modify `GetDelegate` method to set value into `myStruct.myField`?

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int myField;
}

public delegate void SetHandler(object source, object value);

private static SetHandler GetDelegate(Type type, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("setter", typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }, type, true);
    ILGenerator setGenerator = dm.GetILGenerator();

    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setGenerator.DeclareLocal(type);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, type);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, 0);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, fieldInfo.FieldType);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldInfo);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, 0);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Box, type);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (SetHandler)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(SetHandler));
}

MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();
myStruct.myField = 3;

FieldInfo fi = typeof(MyStruct).GetField("myField", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

SetHandler setter = GetDelegate(typeof(MyStruct), fi);
setter(myStruct, 111);
Console.WriteLine(myStruct.myField);
```

Comment: This is why we don't work with mutable structs.  You're mutating a copy of the struct.  Create a new version of the struct with the fields initialized to what you want them to be.

Comment: Related [set a field of struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272454/generate-dynamic-method-to-set-a-field-of-a-struct-instead-of-using-reflection?rq=1) question *may* be what you are after... Side note: nicely asked question with good sample... but whole thing you are trying to achieve is very confusing and unlikely to work the way you want in most cases...

Comment: Oops; I realize I'd screwed up my answer; edited - however, it would work a lot better as a `ref MyStruct`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: [I made this mistake again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937935/how-to-mutate-a-boxed-struct-using-il) - fun fact; unbox-any returns the *value*; unbox returns the *pointer to the data* - which allows in-place mutate.

Here's the working IL generation:

```
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, type);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, fieldInfo.FieldType);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldInfo);
    setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

But! This is mutating a boxed copy; you would need to unbox afterwards:

```
    object obj = myStruct;
    setter(obj, 111);
    MyStruct andBackAgain = (MyStruct)obj;
    Console.WriteLine(andBackAgain.myField);
    Console.WriteLine(myStruct.myField);
```

To do it in place, you would probably need the method to take a `ref MyStruct`, or to *return* a `MyStruct`. You *could* return the boxed copy, but that doesn't make it much easier to use. Frankly, it is moot: structs should not generally be mutable.

Comment: @petelids to be fair, I just fixed the OP's IL, but: yes, I do *lots* of IL - very powerful for meta-programming. I use it in protobuf-net, dapper, fast-member, and a few other libraries.

Comment: Edited answer works! andBackAgain.myField is 111. But always myStruct.myField is 3. Is there another way to set value for myStruct.myField without using ref MyStruct using reflection with high performance?

Comment: @cyrus `ref MyStruct` and `TypedReference` are the only things that don't create a copy

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you write a solution with `ref` in delegate? I can use delegate without any generic types! `public delegate void SetHandler(ref object source, object value)`, but with this delegate I get an error: `Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type`

Comment: @Cyrus `ref object` won't help you; that is the same problem; it *has* to be `ref MyStruct`, `MyStruct*` or `TypedReference` if you want to avoid the "mutating a clone" thing. But again, most structs should not be mutable *anyway*.

Comment: [Same thing but using expression trees](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31898080/855432)

Answer (score 12):

I think as Servy points out in the comments it's probably better to not have a mutable struct and instead create a copy of the struct with the new value. You can use the `SetValueDirect` method on the `FieldInfo` instance if you *really* want to use reflection to mutate the struct but it uses the undocumented `__makeref` method to get a [`TypedReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typedreference.aspx).

**I really wouldn't recommend using this code; it's purely to show that this is possible:**

```
MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();
myStruct.myField = 3;

FieldInfo fi = typeof(MyStruct).GetField("myField", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
TypedReference reference = __makeref(myStruct);
fi.SetValueDirect(reference, 111);
Console.WriteLine(myStruct.myField); //prints 111
```

Comment: What is this I don't even... +1 For the `__makeref` keyword, I cannot believe I never stumbled upon that. You just gave me a bunch of stuff to play with.

Comment: @Groo There are more undocumented keywords. `__arglist`, `__refvalue`, `__reftype`. Just google :)

Comment: Thanks @Groo - I think I saw it on [Eric Lippert's](http://ericlippert.com/) blog somewhere and it must have stuck (Sorry, I can't find the direct link). I've never used it other than to play with though and I don't think I ever will :)

Comment: @petelids: Yeah, I just found [this pearl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4764573/69809), looks pretty cool.

Comment: @Groo - that's a really interesting link. I was supposed to be doing some work tonight but I think I may have just lost an hour or two to that link!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to use Reflection to set fields or properties of a structure is to box the structure, pass the boxed structure to `SetField` or `SetProperty`, and then unbox the structure once all desired manipulations are complete.

```
public static class refStructTest
{
    struct S1
    {
        public int x;
        public int y { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("[{0},{1}]", x, y);
        }
    }
    public static void test()
    {
        var s = default(S1);
        s.x = 2;
        s.y = 3;
        Object obj = s;
        var fld = typeof(S1).GetField("x");
        var prop = typeof(S1).GetProperty("y");
        fld.SetValue(obj,5);
        prop.SetValue(obj,6,null);
        s = (S1)obj;
        Console.WriteLine("Result={0}", s);
    }
}
```

According to the ECMA documentation, each value type is associated with two kinds of things: a storage location type and a heap object type.  The heap object type, like all heap object types, will behave with reference semantics; passing a reference to a heap object to a method like `SetValue` will thus modify the object to which the reference was passed.

Note for VB users: VB.NET has a really annoying behavior which almost make sense in the `Option Strict On` dialect, but which exists even in the `Option Strict Off` dialect: if a variable of compile-time type `Object` which holds a reference to a boxed structure is assigned to another variable of that same type or passed as a parameter of type `Object`, VB.NET will store or pass a reference to a copy of the original object.  When writing code like the above in VB.NET, one should make `obj` be of type `ValueType` rather than `Object` to prevent such behavior.

Comment: How to update your method, if the input is struct: public static void test(S1 s) ... but not use (ref S1 s)

Comment: Did you mean "how to make a method update an outside struct: `public static void test(ref S1 s)`, but *note* use of `(ref S1 s)`?  I've probably mistyped "not" for "note" more times than I can remember, but of course it changes the meaning entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Here the code with ref:

```
public delegate void SetHandler<T>(ref T source, object value) where T : struct;

        private static SetHandler<T> GetDelegate<T>(FieldInfo fieldInfo) where T : struct
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("setter", typeof(void), new Type[] { type.MakeByRefType(), typeof(object) }, type, true);
            ILGenerator setGenerator = dm.GetILGenerator();

            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setGenerator.DeclareLocal(type);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stind_Ref);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, fieldInfo.FieldType);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldInfo);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, 0);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Box, type);
            setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                return (SetHandler<T>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(SetHandler<>).MakeGenericType(type));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();
            myStruct.myField = 3;

            FieldInfo fi = typeof(MyStruct).GetField("myField", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            var setter = GetDelegate<MyStruct>(fi);
            setter(ref myStruct, 111);
            Console.WriteLine(myStruct.myField);
        }
```

Comment: Works! Nice solution with ref parameter.

Comment: Can you write a solution without the generic type in delegate? I can use delegate `public delegate void SetHandler(ref object source, object value)`

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers, you can actually box inside the delegate, as long as your method also returns the modified struct.

Since my IL-fu is not that great, this is how you would do it with plain reflection:

```
// the good side is that you can use generic delegates for added type safety
public delegate T SetHandler<T>(T source, object value);

private static SetHandler<T> GetDelegate<T>(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    return (s, val) => 
    { 
        object obj = s; // we have to box before calling SetValue
        fieldInfo.SetValue(obj, val);
        return (T)obj; 
    };
}
```

This means you will need to fetch the return value like this:

```
SetHandler<MyStruct> setter = GetDelegate<MyStruct>(fi);
myStruct = setter(myStruct, 111);
Console.WriteLine(myStruct.myField);
```

But there's no need to box it before calling the `setter`.

Alternatively, you can pass the struct using the `ref` keyword, which would result in:

```
public delegate void SetHandler<T>(ref T source, object value);

private static SetHandler<T> GetDelegate<T>(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    return (ref T s, object val) => 
    { 
        object obj = s;
        fieldInfo.SetValue(obj, val);
        s = (T)obj; 
    };
}

SetHandler<MyStruct> setter = GetDelegate<MyStruct>(fi);
setter(ref myStruct, 111); // no need to return anymore
Console.WriteLine(myStruct.myField);
```

Comment: I have many structs, and one method void SetStructValue(object someStruct, object value). How can I call your method GetDelegate in my method SetStructValue. I cannot call GetDelegate<MyStruct>(fi) because type of someStruct is not the same as typeof(MyStruct). Typeof someStruct can be everythig - any struct!

Comment: If your struct is already boxed to an `object`, then there is no point in using generics and you can use the examples shown in other answers. But if you have a value type variable before calling your `SetStructValue`, then you should consider making that method generic also.