# get and set object property using Expression trees instead of Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, dynamic-method

I would like to dynamically get and set an objects properties as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
}

public class Testing
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var p = new Person();

        SetValue(p, "Name", "Henry");

        var name = GetValue(p, "Name");
    }
}
```

Please could I get help creating the GetValue and SetValue methods using dynamic method (or expression trees)?

I am intending to save compiled expressions in a dictionary, to speed up future get/set calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really want to use expression trees? for this simple scenario I would try to compile directly into a DynamicMethod using Reflection.Emit API's by getting an IL Generator. But .. for expression trees, i wrote a helper for you:

```
 public class PropertyManager : DynamicObject
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, GetterAndSetter>> _compiledProperties = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, GetterAndSetter>>();

        private static Object _compiledPropertiesLockObject = new object();

        private class GetterAndSetter
        {
            public Action<object, Object> Setter { get; set; }

            public Func<Object, Object> Getter { get; set; }
        }

        private Object _object;

        private Type _objectType;

        private PropertyManager(Object o)
        {
            _object = o;
            _objectType = o.GetType();
        }

        public static dynamic Wrap(Object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
                return null; // null reference will be thrown

            var type = o.GetType();

            EnsurePropertySettersAndGettersForType(type);

            return new PropertyManager(o) as dynamic;
        }

        private static void EnsurePropertySettersAndGettersForType(Type type)
        {
            if (false == _compiledProperties.ContainsKey(type))
                lock (_compiledPropertiesLockObject)
                    if (false == _compiledProperties.ContainsKey(type))
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, GetterAndSetter> _getterAndSetters;
                        _compiledProperties[type] = _getterAndSetters = new Dictionary<string, GetterAndSetter>();

                        var properties = type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

                        foreach (var property in properties)
                        {
                            var getterAndSetter = new GetterAndSetter();
                            _getterAndSetters[property.Name] = getterAndSetter;

                            // burn getter and setter

                            if (property.CanRead)
                            {
                                // burn getter

                                var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "param");

                                Expression propExpression = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(param, type), property), typeof(object));

                                var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propExpression, new[] { param });

                                var compiled = lambda.Compile() as Func<object, object>;
                                getterAndSetter.Getter = compiled;
                            }

                            if (property.CanWrite)
                            {
                                var thisParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object), "this");
                                var theValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object), "value");

                                var isValueType = property.PropertyType.IsClass == false && property.PropertyType.IsInterface == false;

                                Expression valueExpression;
                                if (isValueType)
                                    valueExpression = Expression.Unbox(theValue, property.PropertyType);
                                else
                                    valueExpression = Expression.Convert(theValue, property.PropertyType);

                                var thisExpression = Expression.Property (Expression.Convert(thisParam, type), property);


                                Expression body = Expression.Assign(thisExpression, valueExpression);

                                var block = Expression.Block(new[]
                                {
                                    body,
                                    Expression.Empty ()
                                });

                                var lambda = Expression.Lambda(block, thisParam, theValue);

                                getterAndSetter.Setter = lambda.Compile() as Action<Object, Object>;
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            var memberName = binder.Name;
            result = null;
            Dictionary<string, GetterAndSetter> dict;
            GetterAndSetter getterAndSetter;
            if (false == _compiledProperties.TryGetValue(_objectType, out dict)
                || false == dict.TryGetValue(memberName, out getterAndSetter))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (getterAndSetter.Getter == null)
                throw new NotSupportedException("The property has no getter!");

            result = getterAndSetter.Getter(_object);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            var memberName = binder.Name;

            Dictionary<string, GetterAndSetter> dict;
            GetterAndSetter getterAndSetter;
            if (false == _compiledProperties.TryGetValue(_objectType, out dict)
                || false == dict.TryGetValue(memberName, out getterAndSetter))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (getterAndSetter.Setter == null)
                throw new NotSupportedException("The property has no getter!");

            getterAndSetter.Setter(_object, value);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

And this is how you can use it:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = "mama";
var wrapped = PropertyManager.Wrap(p);

var val = wrapped.Name; // here we are using our compiled method ...
```

It is very obvious that you can extract my compilation logic to use strings instead of letting DLR giving the property name for you :)

Comment: Very complete and well-explained.

Comment: @Timo In the section where the setter gets created, shouldn't the `isValueType` check be made against `property.DeclaringType`, and not `property.PropertyType`? If so, shouldn't the statement `Expression.Unbox(theValue, property.PropertyType)` actually be `Expression.Unbox(thisParam, property.DeclaringType)`? That's how it's done in a couple of other examples I've seen on StackOverflow, namely https://stackoverflow.com/a/36816166/3163495 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158735/3163495. I've tested how those other answers do it and it works fine. Does it matter?

Comment: @user3163495 Testing this answer with a quick .NET Fiddle, I conclude that it works for both class and struct properties. It does not, however, work for struct _containers_ (the object whose properties are addressed). It is possible that the other solutions you mentioned _do_ work with struct containers, and must deal with potential boxing of the container. As for the current answer, it takes the _value_ to assign as an `object`, and thus must unbox it if it is of a value type. That can be identified by the `PropertyType`.