# Boxing behaves differently in C# and VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to pass a structure to a sub/void to fill it with data. In C# this works fine by doing

```
[TestFixture]
public class Boxing
{
    [Test]
    public void BoxingValue()
    {
       var res = (object)new Test();
       SomeVoid(res);         
        Assert.AreEqual(2, ((Test)res).Id);
    }

    public static void SomeVoid(object b)
    {
        var f = b.GetType().GetField("Id");
        f.SetValue(b, 2);
    }

    public struct Test
    {
        public int Id;
    }
}
```

This code passes the test in C# in vb thoug

```
<Test> Public Sub StructTest()
  Dim s As Object
    s = CObj(New Test)
    A(s)
    Assert.AreEqual(2, CType(s, Test).Id)
End Sub

Public Sub A(val As Object)
    Dim f = val.GetType().GetField("Id")
    f.SetValue(val, 2)
End Sub

Public Structure Test
    Public Id As Integer
End Structure
```

Does anyone have a explanation for this..

**STRANGE?**

Comment: I don't get it. Post the full code. What is the type of `res`?

Comment: Yeah, without the declaration of `res` in C#, it's impossible to determine whether code was converted correctly. You need the two missing lines - `Dim s As Object` and `s = CObj(New Test)`.

Comment: my bad.. should be there now

Comment: Can you also include `<Test> Public Sub StructTest()` in C# code and also make sure all class and variable names are consistent? `void a(b)` and `A(val)`, also `struct DtoStruct` vs `Structure Test`.

Comment: This code burns my eyes. Mutable structs... converting C# to VB... using a side-effect of boxing... reflection... gah!

Comment: The code is just for demonstrating the effect of boxing/unboxing constructed for just that in mind. Not productioncode in any way

Comment: @PEtter: even so, real-world code that actually is affected by the difference in behavior is still broken. As for the explanation, I think rather than posting here your best bet is to look at the IL (see ildasm.exe, or a tool like dotPeek or Reflector) and see what each compiler generated. I don't know off the top of my head why VB.NET would treat a boxed struct differently, but the answer is in the IL.

Comment: @PEtter Fair enough, but still.

Comment: tried byref but that didn't help. I will take a look at the IL tomorrow

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use DirectCast rather than CType?

Comment: Yes. Seems the boxing 'disapears' when calling the sub.

Comment: I will give this a more extensive research tomorrow, and post an update

Comment: Actually I remember this, is the fact that the reflection call f.SetValue(val, 2) doesn't actually change val but a copy of val, I'll see if I can remember the solution!

Comment: boxing should be the soloution for that :)

Comment: btw I also tried to change the value directly via a direct cast. but didn't help either..

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth can you elaborate on the "side-effect of boxing"?

Comment: @MillieSmith Yes. In this instance, boxing is creating an object wrapper around one copy of a struct implicitly. This is passed into the method and mutated. Were this struct passed into the method as a struct, the mutation would not have affected the caller's copy. The side-effect is the desired "reference" behaviour by wrapping the struct, which could have been done explicitly with a custom class, or with the `ref` keyword. Might not be a textbook example of side-effect, but it's smelly nonetheless.

Comment: That said, the question has matured a little into a more hypothetical question, where this code simply demonstrates a difference requiring explanation.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is a known limitation with the use of `SetValue` in VB when passing structures (even if the variable itself is declared as an `Object`).  If you look at the contents of `val` within `A` before and after the call to `SetValue`, you'll see that it doesn't change the value of the struct.  The explanation I've seen is that VB internally boxes the underlying value *again* (via a call to `GetObjectValue`), creating a *copy*, and changes the copy's value.

One workaround I've seen is to cast the value to a `ValueType` and the call `SetValue` on it (you also need to change the parameter to be explicitly ByRef:

```
Public Sub A(ByRef val As Object)
    Dim f = val.GetType().GetField("Id")
    If val.GetType.IsValueType Then
        Dim vt As ValueType = val
        f.SetValue(vt, 2)
        val = vt
    Else
        f.SetValue(val, 2)
    End If    
End Sub
```

Of course, this complexity just reinforces the principle that mutable structs should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: No problem. Giving you a +1. In any case, this makes me hate VB even more. You have to make a copy of the struct every time you do reflection on it.

Comment: @MillieSmith: Just follow the guidelines - structures are supposed to be immutable. You never use SetValue on them in real life. If VB does not let you develop a spherical horse in vacuum, it's not a good reason to hate it.

Comment: I belive you are on to someting here. I also made it work doing this modifications. But that was not the actual question :) I belive the code 'is the same' in c# an vb but i compile to difrent IL and that is what scares me.

Comment: Your "question" was asking for an explanation - that is the explanation.  VB internally boxes the value _again_ and works with a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

See [Reflection on structure differs from class - but only in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448158/reflection-on-structure-differs-from-class-but-only-in-code) for an explaination, but the summary is:

```
f.SetValue(val*, 2)
```

*{at this point val is being passed by value, ie it is a copy that is being updated}

as for a workaround...

```
'Struct workaround of course you only want this for structs!:
Public Sub A(ByRef val As Object)

    Dim x As ValueType
    x = CType(val, ValueType)
    Dim f = x.GetType().GetField("Id")
    f.SetValue(x, 2)
    val = x
End Sub
```

Obviously you'll need to protect yourself to only run this for structs...

Comment: The val parameter would also need to be passed "ByRef", wouldn't it?